# What is the name of this common algorithm?

Tags: language-agnostic

Here's the problem - I think it's a very common one with a well documented answer, but I'm not sure what the name of it is to find the answer:

I have a number n(260) between 0 and x(359).

I want to add a value of 100 to n but instead of the result being 360 I want it to cycle back round to 0

It works the other way as well e.g. n minus 270 should equal 349

Any ideas if the algorithm has a name?

Comment: [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do some reading up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the modulo operation is right way to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

It is a mod function.  If you take something like 260 mod 360 the answer would be 260.  If you take 360 mod 360 you get 0.  It's equivalent to the remainder of euclidean division.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're asking about modul_to operation, or division reminder.

```
n_new = (n_old + 100) % (x + 1)
n_new = (260 + 100) % 360
```

UPD: values (n_old, n_new) need define as "unsigned int", for always get positive reminder.